# Color de la barra de navegación al abrir teclado

Tags: java, android

Así cambio el color de mi barra de navegación (la inferior):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
}
```

Pero cuando abro el *teclado* se pone negra, ¿es posible que eso no pase o cambiar el color negro de la barra cuando el teclado se abre?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Adjunto foto, ¿Es posible o solamente depende del teclado?

Comment: Hasta donde yo he podido ver a día de hoy es normal que la barra inferior se pinte de color negro, que es su color normal.

Comment: Claro, pero yo le tengo el color cambio y funciona, pero cuando el teclado se abre se pinta de negro, cuando vuelvo a cerrar el teclado vuelve al color que yo le tengo asignado, por eso pregunto si hay posibilidad de cambiar el color de la barra cuando el teclado está abierto, igual no es posible y solamente depende del teclado.. @Curro

Comment: Eso es lo que te decía antes con mi comentario, que hasta donde yo se una vez abierto el teclado es normal que la barra se pinte de negro y es cosa del teclado.